# FlowLayout in Swing doesn't move to the next line

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, flowlayout

I'm using a flow layout inside a scroll panel. I keep adding button expecting them to add to the next line when there is no more available space, but they just keep adding.

[image]

I want the scroll bar to only scroll vertically, not horizontally.

My code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 6, 6));

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) panel.add(new JButton("asd"));
```

Comment: No it doesn't.  That's just the way flow layout works.  I don't know what you could use to fix this, I think GridLayout might be the best.  I wrote a long time ago code to gut and 'fix' FlowLayout to work like you want, but I don't know where that code is now (probably long gone).

Comment: The question is a duplicate, and here's the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11909455/3500521 (A different, custom layout manager.) Variant for vertical use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8202614/3500521

Comment: I don't mind dumping FlowLayout. I just want the buttons to keep adding vertically when the horizontal space is over. Any idea? In what way could I use GridLayout?

Comment: `In what way could I use GridLayout?` - you can't. `Any idea?` - you have already been given links to answers.