# GridBagLayout controls alignment in Swing

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have this window that has a `JScrollPane` almost all over it. I'm adding large buttons (that have images attached to them) to it and I expect them to keep adding downwards, thats why I'm using a `GridBagLayout` and I set `gbc.gridx, gbc.gridy` everytime I add a button.

The scrolling thing works fine:
[image]

but the problem is, when I add less than 4 buttons, they align to the center of the row, instead to the left side as I want them to. Like this

[image]

Any idea how can I align them to the left? I tried `gbc.anchor` and `gbc.fill` but no luck. Thanks

Here's the panel inside my `JScrollPane`

```
private JPanel imagesPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        //c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

        //add all images as buttons
        List<PuzzleImage> imageList = _imageLoader.getImageCollection().getAllImages();
        for(PuzzleImage puzzleImage : imageList) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { //ignore this, just for debugging. i add 3 images
                ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(puzzleImage.getLowScaleImage());

                c.gridx = x;
                c.gridy = y;
                c.weightx = 1.0;

                JButton btn = new JButton(imageIcon);
                btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ImageLoader.LOW_SCALE_IMAGE_SIZE, ImageLoader.LOW_SCALE_IMAGE_SIZE));
                panel.add(btn, c);

                x++;
                if(x>=4) {
                    x = 0;
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }

        return panel;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the problem is, when I add less than 4 buttons, they align to the center of the row, instead to the left side as I want them to

At least one of the components need to have a `weightx` constraint greater than 0.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The section that explains how the constraints works will provide more information.

Why are you even using a `GridBagLayout`? You were given a simple solution I your last question: [FlowLayout in Swing doesn't move to the next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192589/flowlayout-in-swing-doesnt-move-to-the-next-line). Then you don't even need to worry about constraints.

Or you could use a `GridLayout`  You simply define that you want 4 columns and components automatically wrap. You may need to nest panels so components don't shrink/grow depending on the size of the frame.

Basic code is:

```
JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
JPanel buttons = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 4) );

for (...)
{
    JButton button = new JButton(...);
    buttons.add( button );
}

frame.add(wrapper);
```

Comment: The flawlayout was about a different case. Also it doesn't add images to the right, only to the bottom. I want to add images to both directions

Comment: The suggestion wasn't to use the FlowLayout. I guess you didn't read the links you were provided for the layout manager to use. `it doesn't add images to the right, only to the bottom.` - no idea what that means. Components are added to the top row and then the right and it wraps when the row is full, which is exactly what your code is doing now, except your hard code the logic.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a precise answer without your code, but here's a possible solution:

You could take your JPanel holding all the pictures and nest it inside another JPanel to make it anchor to the left like so:

```
JPanel pictures = /* already defined */;
JPanel container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

container.add(pictures, BorderLayout.WEST);
//add container to your scroll container
```