# BoxLayout adding components dynamic (two cols)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I want to create a JPanel where i could add Text Fields *min 1 max 12*. (So I decided to create JPanel which have enough space to contain 12 text fields in 6 rows and 2 cols). It’s depends how many check boxes will be checked by user. What is more those Text fields should appeared form **top-to-bottom** with **left edge alignment** in this JPanel. And every time one of those check boxes is unchecked specified Text Field is remove form JPanel, and rest of them move to this empty space (*shift up to cover its space*).

So I create text field if it’s necessary, not create all at the beginning  and setVisible(false). I think this is better solution.

For example:

```
//each JTexyField have the same size

JPanel panel = new JPanel(new LayoutManager()); //in my case BoxLayout
If(checkboxEuro == chcecked) {
   JTextField fieldEuro = new JTextField(); 
   panel.add(fieldEuro);
}
else if(checkbox2 == ...) panel.add(fieldDolar);
...
If(checkboxDolar = = unchecked) panel.remove(fieldDolar);
```

(And I don’t care where this button appeared, important thing is  that, this button should appeared after existing button in this panel)

#### What i get

If there isn’t enough space on the bottom in JPanel, LM should add this Text Field in next column starting from top. In this example 6x2 if I tried to add another (7-th) text field , and in this column isn’t enough space, it should appeared in second column on top, but it isn’t. When I use BoxLayout 7-th text field  appeared half on JPanel and half above.

What should I do? Change Layout Manager, or maybe there is option which don’t allow to cross the bounds of JPanel?  **(this is the most important)**

I get this: [image: panel picture 1], and want this: [image: panel picture 2]

(Sorry for language – it’s first time)

---- Edit---

**In case we have misunderstood:** Let me get this right, i'm looking for methot/option in different LM which  help me to "scroll" rows if there's no space to add TextField(7-th in this example), should be moved to next (column) on TOP. I don't defined 2 columns but area of this JPanel let me think like there was a space which hold 2 columns of JTextField. When I add all 12 Fields and remove for example second rest of them should shift up to cover this space

```
1 4            2 5
2 5  remove 1  3 6
3 6            4
```

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196530/java-vertical-flowlayout-with-horizontal-scrolling

Comment: +1 for screenshots :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are constructing the JPanel after all of these checkbox values are known. In that case, just determine how many textfields you need to add first, then create your layout. To simplify your code I recommend that you place the checkbox elements in an array.
Then you can do something like this:

```
JCheckBox[] checkBoxes = new JCeckBox[12];
JTextField[] currencyFields = new JTextField[12];
//Then in your constructor you can initialize the Checkboxes, but not the text fields.
checkBoxes[0] = new JCheckBox("Euros");
checkBoxes[1] = new JCheckBox("Hungarian Forint");
// and so on.

//Compute how many text fields we need:
private int numberOfBoxesChecked() {
   c=0;
   for(JCheckBox cb : checkBoxes ) {
       if(cb.isSelected())
           c++;
   }
   return c;
}
```

Now when you build the panel you can use `numberOfBoxesChecked()` to determine how to initialize your Layout.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault i don't mention that I wrote this only to describe a problem. Your answer is very helpful, but i want to resolve problem with Layout Manger

Comment: Do you mean you want to build your own layout manager that is smart enough to know when to use one column and when to use two?

Comment: First of all I want to use defined Layout Managers , i thought there is some method/opction (unknown for me, I'm beginner in Swing) which let me do this right. But if don't exist I try to build own LM

Comment: If you are new to swing, I would recommend getting more experience using a layout before attempting to build your own layout manager. When you want to add or remove a component, you can always just re-create the window or the JPanel, so the solution I presented will work fine and involve less work than creating your own layout.