# Swing BoxLayout components not being arranged

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

When I use a `FlowLayout`, components move to a new row when they reach the limit. I want exactly the same, but Vertical. Doing a little bit of research, I found that what I want to do should be accomplish using `BoxLayout`. But my box layout only uses one column.

[image]
I want the second panel to detect that its space is not enough to display all the components in the main panel and place it in the second column.

Here is the code to reproduce the issue.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestingMain {

    static JFrame frame;

    public static JPanel createUI() {
        JPanel UIPanel = new JPanel();
        UIPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(UIPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();

        firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(firstPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        firstPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Box 1"));

        JCheckBox ch1 = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox ch2 = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox ch3 = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox ch4 = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox ch5 = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox ch6 = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox ch7 = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");


        firstPanel.add(ch1);
        firstPanel.add(ch2);
        firstPanel.add(ch3);
        firstPanel.add(ch4);
        firstPanel.add(ch5);
        firstPanel.add(ch6);
        firstPanel.add(ch7);


        secondPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Box 2"));
        secondPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(secondPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JCheckBox alarmLimitedBatt = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox alarmNotEnoughBatt = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox alarmLowBatt = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox alarmCriticalBatt = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox stateOfCharge = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");
        JCheckBox sleepState = new JCheckBox("checkbox!");

        secondPanel.add(alarmLimitedBatt);
        secondPanel.add(alarmNotEnoughBatt);
        secondPanel.add(alarmLowBatt);
        secondPanel.add(alarmCriticalBatt);
        secondPanel.add(stateOfCharge);
        secondPanel.add(sleepState);

        UIPanel.add(firstPanel);
        UIPanel.add(secondPanel);
        return  UIPanel;

    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        frame = new JFrame("BoxLayout Issue");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JPanel newContentPane = createUI();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.setSize(800,250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no layout manager in the JDK that does that. You could try using the `VericalFlowLayout` which is a customization based on the FlowLayout. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196530/java-vertical-flowlayout-with-horizontal-scrolling/8199584#8199584

Comment: If all you want is to have `secondPanel` right of `firstPanel` use `UIPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(UIPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));`  Side note: see [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)

Comment: Hey, I love you @camickr . Thanks a lot :-)